# Android: Sending error reports to server using acra (couchDB)

Tags: android

I am new to Android Development. I install CouchDB on the server and created a user. I use following code in my app.

@ReportsCrashes (

```
 formKey = "",
 reportType = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Type.JSON,
 httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT,
 formUri = "localhost:5984/acra-myapp/_design/acra-storage/_update/report",
 formUriBasicAuthLogin = "admin",
 formUriBasicAuthPassword = "admin"
```

)

when i run my app from android device it give me following error:

```
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348): Failed to send crash report for 1391497913000-approved.stacktrace
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348): org.acra.sender.ReportSenderException: Error while sending JSON report via Http PUT
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:228)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at org.acra.SendWorker.sendCrashReport(SendWorker.java:179)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:141)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:77)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348): Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to `*` refused
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:152)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:225)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    ... 3 more
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to  after 3000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:250)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:178)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:859)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    ... 10 more
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
02-04 12:46:26.606: E/ACRA(348):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:234)
```

Can't seem to figure out this error.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You access your computer's localhost as 10.0.2.2 from emulator. more details 
    http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias

try below code

```
 formKey = "",
 reportType = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Type.JSON,
 httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT,
 formUri = "10.0.2.2:5984/acra-mediwatch/_design/acra-storage/_update/report",
 formUriBasicAuthLogin = "admin",
 formUriBasicAuthPassword = "admin"
```

Add the INTERNET permission to your manifest file.

You have to add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Its working fine when i use localhost as 10.0.2.2 for emulator.But when i install couchDB on different server and call 208.109.91.98:5984  this from emulator or from device it give me above error.

Answer (score 1):

"Connection refused" means that the host could be reached but there wasn't anything listening in the target port. So, first make sure you have your server running on 208.109.91.98 port 5984.